# Using the PayPal option for no price with Drupal 7 Ubercart

Tags: ubercart, payment-gateways

PayPal has an option to set up a Buy Now Button with no set price. That is, this is not a free item, it allows the viewer to choose an amount, as in for a donation (I have also had a client use this to allow clients to prepay custom services from their site). This is really great for folks who want to make a donation to a non-profit with an amount that has some special significance for themselves personally.

But, Sell Price is a required field in an Ubercart Product. Has anyone found a way to allow a viewer to enter their own price?